# Is there a good character sheet set up for the Unchained Variant rules, especially Consolidated Skills?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-sheets

My personal abilities at graphic design are horrible.  I've tried making my own character sheets, to no avail.  So now I'm searching - one of my campaigns is using lots of the Pathfinder Unchained variant rules, and I could use a sheet for it.

My biggest concern is the Consolidated and Background skill systems.  Even the most editable sheet I've found has the names of all the default skills hardcoded in.  I don't mind if there's a lot of blank space, but I need a sheet that either a) doesn't have anything in the skill name slots, allowing us to customize our own skill lists; or b) has the names of the Consolidated Skills prefilled, with space below to write in our Background Skills.

Other options that a great sheet will include, but aren't strictly necessary (arranged from most to least useful):

A ridiculous amount of space for feats

Space somewhere for Loyalties (or just a lot of generic spaces in something like "Special Abilities" or even feats)

A few spaces (can be generic) for various point pools like Stamina and Hero Points

The Wound Thresholds somewhere near the HP section

A track or two for new Poisons and Diseases

Comment: Not sure what happened to my formatting there, I'll fix it.

Comment: I take it you don't have any kind of pdf-editing software, like Acrobat Pro? If you have a sheet whose layout you like but that has too much of the wrong information (and/or not enough blank space to add your own options), I should be able to edit it into fillable blanks for you. Or someone you know who has that kind of software might be willing to do that, if you know of anyone.

Comment: @Alyksandrei I don't.  I poked around some editors meant for character sheets, but I can't find one I can import an existing sheet into to edit it.  I was hoping someone had made one by now and my Google-fu just wasn't finding it;  Unchained's kinda new but not *that* new.  I'm a pretty bad nitpicker, so I won't ask someone to make one especially for me - I'm the stereotypical "client from Hades" who would still be asking for little changes two months from now.  Thanks for the offer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very kind graphic designer helped me out, and gave me permission to share her work!  It's presently available at ENWorld, and you are welcome to reupload it to other places as long as you don't claim it's your own work.  The designer has chosen to remain anonymous.

http://www.enworld.org/forum/rpgdownloads.php?do=download&downloadid=1288

Answer (score 3):

My [Dyslexic Character Sheets](https://www.dyslexic-charactersheets.com/) have consolidated skills (and a lot of space for feats and special abilities). They don't have the wounds threshold, stamina, hero points etc though.

Comment: Looks awesome bro!

Answer (score 1):

Why not make an Excel spreadsheet instead?  It may not look quite as pretty, but you will be able to make the layout however you want, and included whatever rules and spaces you will need.

I've been playing RPG's for a few years, and at this point I use Excel for all my character sheets, things tend to get too insane with all the equipment and buffs in later levels to want to stick to a paper sheet.

Comment: Designing a printable one takes a bit more skill, though. I've come to the conclusion that a printable pdf sheet plus excel-generated notecards works best for me. OPs question seems to indicate that he wants something that is also suitable for printing. I've tried to do that in excel, and it's harder than it might seem. I, too, am lacking in the graphic design department.

Comment: @Alyksandrei is right, most of my Pathfinder games happen at my friend's house where we play with books and paper only.  An Excel sheet doesn't print well at all.  I've actually got one that I'd like to post as a self-answer now, I'm just trying to get in touch with the graphic designer who made it for me again to make sure I have permission to post it.